# Amazon ec2 folder missing

Tags: amazon-ec2, settings

```
To set permissions on the settings file

On your Amazon EC2 instance, at a command prompt, use the following command to set     permissions:

sudo chmod 666 /var/www/html/sites/default/settings.php
```

except I don't have a `www` folder in my instance

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-242-118-215 ~]$ cd /
[ec2-user@ip-10-242-118-215 /]$ ls
bin   cgroup  etc   lib    local       media  opt   root  selinux  sys  usr
boot  dev     home  lib64  lost+found  mnt    proc  sbin  srv      tmp  var
[ec2-user@ip-10-242-118-215 /]$ cd var
[ec2-user@ip-10-242-118-215 var]$ ls
account  db     games  local  log   nis  preserve  run    tmp
cache    empty  lib    lock   mail  opt  racoon    spool  yp
```

Please advise, did I forget to install something that the amazon instructions assumed I knew about?

Running 64bit Amazon linux ami march 2012

I feel like the webserver is missing?

Comment: Would you be able to link to the source for those instructions?

Comment: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/gettingstarted/latest/computebasics-linux/getting-started-deploy-app-download-app.html

Comment: That tutorial may be good for the EC2 side of things, but expects you to use a Drupal AMI with Apache preinstalled. If you aren't going that route, I'd find another tutorial to follow for the step by step instructions on how to set up such an environment. The (at least) two steps additional steps needed are: `yum install httpd` and the download and extraction of the Drupal code. You could, in theory use any other webserver (e.g. nginx, lighttpd) instead of Apache - however /var/www/ and commands like service httpd start are associated with Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation you linked, it sounds like you're expecting to use an AMI with Drupal preinstalled, but you're using a normal, non-Drupal version.  Make sure that you follow the documentation starting at [Step 3: Find a Suitable AMI](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/gettingstarted/latest/computebasics-linux/getting-started-find-ami.html) to get an AMI with Drupal.  Then, you should have the appropriate folders (and files) installed.  Best of luck!

Comment: ah okay! well I dont need drupal, but I could always install it later since I have root access and can get dependences right?

Comment: If Drupal is installed and setup from a package, then yes--but since you're talking about EC2, all you'd need to do is fire up a brand new instance!  That's the beauty of EC2. :)